# set table name with hibernate name parameters

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to set a table name dynamically so that I use `query.setText(tname,abc)`

e.g: `select a.name from :tname where a.id = '2'`

I used `setText()` because when I use `setString()` it says "`tname is a invalid parameter`" because I assume that Hibernate adds '' when setting string parameters.

But even `setText()` does not help and gives the same exception.

How can I set the table name dynamically?

***Reply to PSR:***

So you mean replace table name as a java string replacement. But then we can not take support of sql injections prevention etc from hibernate right? Also How we bind parameters in hibernate in a situation where like statement,

Eg: name like "%:name%"

This also gives me Illegal argument exception: Parameter does not exist as a named parameter when i try to bind it using query.setString(name,"def");

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate will not do this for you, because it works with `PreparedStatement`s, and you can't prepare a statement where the table being queried isn't known yet.

I don't see why you would be exposing table *names* to end users, so preventing SQL injection doing a regular string substitution should be easy. You use some sort of business logic to determine the correct table from a list that only you know. The table name isn't coming from user input at all.

Depending on your choice of RDBMS, you may find a [discriminator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-discriminator) column, or **table inheritance** with partitioning to be a better way of handling a situation where identical queries are made against different tables.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to set table name dynamically.You can set dynamically column names.it is not possible to set table name

try like this

```
select a.name from '+table name+'where a.id = '2'
```

Comment: please find the reply in the question

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, There are 2 ways to resolve this issue:

1- If you are using Spring and Hibernate together, you could use [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) and it would be like #{#entityName} as it is described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.7.x/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions)

```
@Entity
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  Long id;

  String lastname;
}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {

  @Query("select u from #{#entityName} u where u.lastname = ?1")
  List<User> findByLastname(String lastname);
}
```

2-You could use [CriteriaBuilder](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries) like

```
CriteriaQuery<YourEntity> cr = cb.createQuery(YourEntity.class);
Root<YourEntity> root = cr.from(YourEntity.class);
cr.select(root);
```

I copied the source codes from the provided links and they are described there much better